# Load a PHP file in in a tab/div in HTML

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a HTML file with 3 tabs. I want to load a **PHP** file when the user clicks on **one specific tab (Tab1)** out of 3 tabs.

**Tabs Code:**

```
<div id="content">
<div role="tabpanel">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"  id="main_tab_content">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab1" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab2" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Tab1 Code:**

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">Yet to be integrated.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and so on for **Home and Tab 2**.

**jquery load code:**

```
<script>
$( ".tab1" ).load( "/test/index.php" );
</script>
```

The code was written by a colleague, I am trying to use the same html layout to load my PHP file.
So far tried with with jquery load and i think issue i am facing is cz of  the div class/id am using in load.

Any inputs will be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: `$( ".tab1" )` No element with a class "tab1"

Comment: id of Tab 1 is tab1, How can i load php file into Tab 1 in this case?

Comment: That would be `$( "#tab1" )` then

Comment: @NicoHaase, My query is to which class or id, i should use in jquery so that i can load my php file in Tab 1

Comment: @brombeer, tried that too, no use, loads "Yet to be integrated." only, not the php file

Comment: what should that php file do? is it executed as php or only show the text of that php file?

Comment: @ZaidYasyaf, The PHP file contains mysql query and data tables and etc, here i just want it to be displayed when clicked on Tab 1 so that the user can proceed on using that PHP file. That file has its own interface

Comment: you can use `<?php include 'file.php';?>` inside your tab1 div. Or you can use `ajax.get` then put the response to your tab1 div.

Comment: @ZaidYasyaf, when the php include is used, it just downloads the file.

Comment: it should not be, here is the example -> https://tryphp.w3schools.com/showphp.php?filename=demo_include1 . try to not use jquery to load the php file manually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242528/discussion-between-sss-and-zaid-yasyaf).

Comment: "My query is to which class or id, i should use in jquery so that i can load my php file in Tab 1" - that's not really relevant. Use whatever fits your need, and write the jQuery selector accordingly

Comment: Are you running this on a webserver (http://localhost) that knows how to handle `.php` files? Can you run a simple `.php` script on your server?

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tab_1').click(function(){
   
$.get( "/test/index.php", function( data ) {
  $( ". tab_1" ).html( data );
});
})
})
</script>
```

*$( ".tab_1" ).html( data );* --> will receive all content from index.php
change class .tab_1 to another class that you want to put content